# why does this match return two results when only one exists

Tags: javascript, regex

Why does this match return two identical matches when only one exists in the string?

```
/^(.*)$/m


<textarea id="input">one    two three   four    five
1111    2222222 333 444444  555
1111    2222222 333 444444  555
1111    2222222 333 444444  555
    1111    2222222 333 444444  55</textarea>  

var str = $("#input").val();

var arr = str.match(/^(.*)$/m);

console.dir(arr); 
/*
Array[2]
    0: "one two three   four    five"
    1: "one two three   four    five"
    index: 0
    input: "one two three   four    five↵1111   2222222 333 444444  555↵1111    2222222 333 444444  555↵1111    2222222 333 444444  555↵    1111    2222222 333 444444  55"
*/
```

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/UcIKUDaF/1/edit)

Comment: In this case, you may instead want to split on newlines rather than use a regular expression like that: `var arr = str.split("\n");`

Comment: @IQAndreas Good point. I will in fact do that instead. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have two matches. The first entry in the array is the entire match, the second is the result of the first capture group (which incidentally is the entire match).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

> If the regular expression does not include the g flag, returns the
>   same result as regexp.exec(string).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec

> The returned array has the matched text as the first item, and then
>   one item for each capturing parenthesis that matched containing the
>   text that was captured.